# Setting the seed for betarnd() in Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to set the seed for `betarnd()` so that every time I re-run my code, I use the same values generated by `betarnd()`. In a previous version of Matlab on someone else's computer, it suffices to do

```
randn('seed', num)
rand('seed', num)
```

and she can get the same set of random values sampled from the beta distribution each time `betarnd(0.5,0.5,[1,15])` is run, for instance. However, in my case, although I set the seeds as shown above, I get different values. What could be causing this discrepancy? And how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab changed its policies and syntaxes since version 2014. Have a look at their [explanation page](https://es.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015a/matlab/math/updating-your-random-number-generator-syntax.html). Basically, you can now set the seed using `rng(sd)` before using the function `rand` or `randn` as usual.

Comment: So this might be a stupid question, but should we get the same results from `betarnd(0.5,0.5,[1,5])` in two different machines, using `rng` in one of them and `randn` plus `rand` in the other?

Comment: No, you'll see different behaviors as far as I know. This is because the pseudo-random number generator used is not the same. Matlab recommends the usage of the `rng(seed)` syntax in all cases. I have tried and it runs at least on R2012b, it is the oldest version I own. When using `rand('seed', num)`, you actually seed a specific, legacy RNG, which is not the one used by `betarnd(...)`, which leads to different results. I hope this answers your question.